# spawn pictures and move to the top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page on which hearts are created and moved to the top of the page.

I want that instead of the created hearts, they spawn and move to the top of the picture.

I tried to do something like this:

`$('.bg_heart').append("<div class='heart'><img src='https://i.imgur.com/lQqgp8Y.png'></div>");`

But it didn't work.

Or do I need to use something else to create pictures?

How can I do it please help me!

```js
var love = setInterval(function() {
    var r_num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40) + 1;
    var r_size = Math.floor(Math.random() * 65) + 10;
    var r_left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    var r_bg = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25) + 100;
    var r_time = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 5;

    $('.bg_heart').append("<div class='heart' style='width:" + r_size + "px;height:" + r_size + "px;left:" + r_left + "%;background:rgba(255," + (r_bg - 25) + "," + r_bg + ",1);-webkit-animation:love " + r_time + "s ease;-moz-animation:love " + r_time + "s ease;-ms-animation:love " + r_time + "s ease;animation:love " + r_time + "s ease'></div>");

    $('.bg_heart').append("<div class='heart' style='width:" + (r_size - 10) + "px;height:" + (r_size - 10) + "px;left:" + (r_left + r_num) + "%;background:rgba(255," + (r_bg - 25) + "," + (r_bg + 25) + ",1);-webkit-animation:love " + (r_time + 5) + "s ease;-moz-animation:love " + (r_time + 5) + "s ease;-ms-animation:love " + (r_time + 5) + "s ease;animation:love " + (r_time + 5) + "s ease'></div>");

    $('.heart').each(function() {
        var top = $(this).css("top").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
        var width = $(this).css("width").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
        if (top <= -100 || width >= 150) {
            $(this).detach();
        }
    });
}, 500);
```

```css
html,body{
  height:100%
}

.bg_heart {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden
 }

.heart {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -m-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg)
 }

.heart:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50%;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: inherit;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.heart:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -50%;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: inherit;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes love {
  0%{top:110%}
}
@-moz-keyframes love {
  0%{top:110%}
}
@-ms-keyframes love {
  0%{top:110%}
}
@keyframes love {
  0%{top:110%}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="header-plugin"></div>

<div class="bg_heart"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add styles and everything will work

```
style='left:" + r_left + "%;-webkit-animation:love " + r_time + "s ease;-moz-animation:love " + r_time + "s ease;-ms-animation:love " + r_time + "s ease;animation:love " + r_time + "s ease'
```

```js
var love = setInterval(function() {
    var r_num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40) + 1;
    var r_size = Math.floor(Math.random() * 65) + 10;
    var r_left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    var r_bg = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25) + 100;
    var r_time = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 5;

 $('.bg_heart').append("<div class='heart' style='left:" + r_left + "%;-webkit-animation:love " + r_time + "s ease;-moz-animation:love " + r_time + "s ease;-ms-animation:love " + r_time + "s ease;animation:love " + r_time + "s ease'><img src='https://i.imgur.com/lQqgp8Y.png'></div>");

    $('.heart').each(function() {
        var top = $(this).css("top").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
        var width = $(this).css("width").replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
        if (top <= -100 || width >= 150) {
            $(this).detach();
        }
    });
}, 500);
```

```css
html,body{
  height:100%
}

.bg_heart {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden
 }

.heart {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -m-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg)
 }

.heart:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50%;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: inherit;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.heart:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -50%;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: inherit;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes love {
  0%{top:110%}
}
@-moz-keyframes love {
  0%{top:110%}
}
@-ms-keyframes love {
  0%{top:110%}
}
@keyframes love {
  0%{top:110%}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="header-plugin"></div>

<div class="bg_heart"></div>
```